# Why is this function being invoked?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I just want to assign a variable to a function so it can be invoked later but in this fiddel the function is invoked every time I press button 'invoke'

Should it not just assign the function to the varialbe 'fun' and not call the alert ?

fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/vkvUR/

code :

```
$("#button").click(myFun);

    <input name="Button3" type="button" value="Invoke" id="button">

    function myFun(myarg){   
        var fun = alert(myarg); 

    }  

    function myFunParam(myFun){    
        if (typeof myFun === "function")       
            myFun('foo'); // alerts "foo" 
    }
```

Comment: Type `var fun = alert('foo');` in the console and see what happens ;) `alert` is invoked because you are calling it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to assign an anonymous function to `fun` containing your `alert` call.

---

Change:

```
var fun = alert(myarg);
```

To:

```
var fun = function(){
   alert(myarg); 
}
```

---

http://jsfiddle.net/Curt/vkvUR/1/

And heres a version calling `fun()`:

http://jsfiddle.net/Curt/vkvUR/2/

Answer (score 0):

Change `var fun = alert(myarg);`  to  `var fun = function(){alert(myarg)};` if you want to use variable `fun` later

Answer (score 0):

`alert(myFun)` invokes the alert method which then causes a popup.  Perhaps you meant something like this.  When you pass parameters to a function within parens after the function name, it will be invoked.  To reference a function without invoking it, leave out the parameters.

```
​var foo = alert;
foo("bar")​​​​​​​​​​​; //alerts "bar"
```